# How can I use the terminal to put put files in a directory into folders, grouping them based on name?

Tags: terminal, pdf

I have a large directory with pdf files in it (several thousand). The files are all named with a 5-digit number at the beginning like this:

```
Directory
|___00001 file 1.pdf
|___20000 file 1.pdf
|___20000 file 2.pdf
|___20001 file 1.pdf
|
```

I need to create a folder for each job number and put the files with that number into that folder like this:

```
Directory
|____00001
| |____00001 file 1.pdf
|____20000
| |____20000 file 1.pdf
| |____20000 file 2.pdf
|____20001
| |____20001 file 1.pdf  
|
```

I found this command:

```
for FILE in *; do FOLDER=$(echo $FILE | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$//'); mkdir "$FOLDER"; mv "$FILE" "$FOLDER" ; done
```

but it just makes a separate file for every folder. I'd like to do this from the Terminal window on my Mac if possible.

Comment: I would split this into two parts. First go through all the files creating the directories, which I think is just remove the mv command. Then loop all over the files mv each one.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` command is just removing the part of the filename beginning with `.`. So it's setting `FOLDER` to the filename without `.pdf`. The regexp should match everything starting from space, not `.`.

```
for FILE in *; do 
    FOLDER=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/ .*$//')
    mkdir -p "$FOLDER"
    mv "$FILE" "$FOLDER" 
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and it works, but only puts one file into the newly created folder, not all files with that number. Like this:

Directory
- 00001:>
-- 00001 file 1.pdf
- 20000:>
-- 20000 file 1.pdf
- 20000 file 2.pdf
-20001:>
-- 20001 file 1.pdf  

Which means I still have to drag all additional files into the created directory. Not sure why..

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one file with the same number prefix?

Comment: I just tested it with the filenames you show in the question and it worked.